# import or install a package within a script

Tags: command-line, import, pip

i have a simple script that takes user inputs on the command line and returns a dataframe.

```
def import_or_install(package):
    try:
        __import__(package)
        print "Importing: "+ package
    except ImportError:
        print "\nInstalling:"+ package
        pip.main(['install', package])

import pip
import argparse
#import pandas

def main():
    import_or_install("pandas")

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage = argparse.SUPPRESS)
    parser.add_argument('-i', 
                        nargs='+', 
                        required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    inputs = args.i

    print pandas.DataFrame(inputs)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I import pandas normally (import pandas) the script works. However, when i try to import pandas using the import_or_install(package) function, I am given the following error:

*NameError: global name 'pandas' is not defined*

My goal is to be able to run this script without the user needing to install he module prior to running the script.

Is this approach a viable way of doing that?

---

To run the script, in the comandline type

*python filename.py -i*, then list some numbers separated by a space.
eg: "python test.py -i 1 2 3 4"

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas

def main():
    import_or_install("pandas")
```

You're trying to import pandas before the package is available. Import
it after installation:

```
def main():
    import_or_install("pandas")
    import pandas
```